# Freemarker: Display the name of a variable/interpolation, instead of the value

Tags: xml, variables, exec, interpolation, freemarker

I'm building an XML triggered project that can have several failure states, and so I'm trying to build these in a way that doesn't require a case for every type of failure. Unfortunately, due to the client's requirements, I am limited to using Freemarker to produce these results (specifically, this is on the Oracle implementation of Freemarker, which includes an ?exec built-in which executes anything in the enclosed string).

There are a lot of variables that might fail in each case, so I'm hoping I can figure out a way to print the name of the variable that failed, instead of manually repeat the message for every case. And this enables the user to quickly troubleshoot issues with the XML payload (or if the problem exists elsewhere).

Example:

```
<#assign errorMsg = r"There was a problem displaying ${thisVarName}.">
${var1!errorMsg?exec}
${var2!errorMsg?exec}
${var3!errorMsg?exec}
```

And the output in case of failure would be:

```
There was a problem displaying var1.
There was a problem displaying var2.
There was a problem displaying var3.
```

Or in the case where only var2 fails, the output would be:

```
The value of var1.
There was a problem displaying var2.
The value of var3.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using a `TemplateExceptionHandler` instead of explicit error handling inside the template?

Comment: And BTW, which Oracle product is this who has forked FreeMarker?

Comment: The Freemarker is within the Responsys product line. I need the errors to go out to users who don't have access to the backend. To my knowledge, TemplateExceptionHandler can't be processed in a way that can be sent out in an email, for instance, available to an external user.

Comment: A `TemplateExceptionHandler` can print some kind of error message into the template output, and continue with the template processing.

Comment: Does that require alteration of the freemarker configuration on the back end? I don't have the ability to alter anything about the system itself, only use freemarker's user-facing commands (builtins, directives, etc.). 

Sorry, I'm not very familiar with how freemarker is implemented from a system perspective.

Comment: Yes, you need to be able to modify the backing Java code, or if FreeMarker is configured from a `properties` file or such, then to modify that. It's a difficult situation if you can't even request such thing from some, as the template itself is only half (or less) of the story. As a last resort, you (or someone) need to be able to add a `TemplateDirectiveModel` class, that you invoke from the template like `<@'com.example.ContinueOnErrorDirective'?new()>...</@>`, and that directive would call `Environment.setTemplateExceptionHandler`.

Comment: I appreciate the help you're offering.

Just to be clear, you're saying that there is no possibility of solving it in a similar roundabout method, as I outlined in the original ask to meet immediate needs?

Comment: Yes, I don't think there's any reasonable solution that's purely done in the template. Well, you could have `<#function var v><#return .vars[v]!"There was a problem displaying ${v}"></#function>` and then instead of `${var1}` you write `${var('var1')}`... But that's quite awkward.  Also something like `${var('var1').foo}` won't work when `var1` is missing,  since the returned string has no `foo` subvariable.

Comment: I think that could work for a solution. I'll have to play with it. I didn't think about using a function for that. I know it's dirty and weird, but that's the bind I'm in haha

Thanks! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as answered.